# Gradle: Set same property to all compile*Kotlin tasks

Tags: gradle, groovy, gradle-plugin

We have a Gradle build, with these blocks:

```
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = 11
    }
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = 11
    }
}
compileTestIntegrationKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = 11
    }
}
```

**Is there a way to apply `kotlinOptions` to all of these tasks?**

Earlier I saw something along the lines of

```
allTasks.withType("compile") { ... }
```

But I can't find any documentation for that. Where is it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As shown here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mpp-configure-compilations.html#configure-all-compilations

You should be able to do:

```
kotlin {
    targets.all {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = 11
            }
        }
    }
}
```